# Randomly generated sorted arrays: search performances comparison

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, random, linear-interpolation

I'm making a program that tests and compares stats of *Multi-Key Sequential* search and *Interpolation* binary search. I'm asking for an advice:

*What is the best way to sort a random-generated array of integers, or even generate it like a sorted one* (if that makes any sense) *in given context?*

I was looking into some sorting techniques, but, if you keep in mind that the accent is on **searching** (not sorting) **performance**, all of the advanced sorts seem rather complicated to be used in just one utility method. Considering that the array has to be **larger than 10<sup>6</sup>** (for testing purposes), Modified/Bubble, Selection or Insertion sorts are not an option.

Additional constraint is that all of the array members must be **unique**.

Now, **my initial idea** was to split the interval **[INT_MIN,INT_MAX]** into **n** intervals (**n** being the array length) and then add a random integer from, **0** to **2<sup>32</sup>/n** (rounded down), to every interval beginning.

**The problem is this**:

I presume that, as **n** rises closer to **2<sup>32</sup>**, like mine does, Interpolation search begins to give better and better results, as it's interpolation gets more accurate.

**However:**

If I rely solely on *pseudo-random number generators* (like `rand();`), their dispersion characteristics dictate the same tendency for a *generated-then-sorted* array, that is - Interpolation gets better at pinpointing the most likely location as the size gets closer to `int` limit. Uniformity/dispersion characteristics get lost as **n** rises to **INT_MAX**, so, due to stated limitations, Interpolation seems to always win.

Feel free do discuss, criticize and clarify this question as you see fit, but I'm rather desperate for an answer, because the test seems to be rigged in Interpolation's favor either way and I want to analyze them fairly. In short: I want to be convinced that my initial idea doesn't tilt the scales in Interpolation's favor even further, and I want to use it because it's ***O(n)***.

Comment: I'm not sure I get this right, do you want a method to generate a random array of sorted integers, with the criteria being that the array is large (10^6)? any definition for what items should be there (spread, uniformity...)?

Comment: @Amit Just that they are random, unique and sorted.

Comment: so [1,2,3,6,7,8] is valid?

Comment: So just walk it.. for every element, set the value to *a[i-1]+random(x)* where *random(x)* is a positive integer bound such that it leaves enough room for n-i elements (should be simple to calculate).

Comment: I'm voting to close it as primarily opinion-based (and too bread also), and such questions are not for this site. However, if "Modified/Bubble, Selection or Insertion" are the only sorting methods you know, then you definitely need more reading on this.

Comment: @Petr Thanks for the opinion, then. :D I said that advanced sorts are not an option because the friggin program has to be crammed in a single .cpp file.

Comment: @Amit Yes, that was my initial intention.

Comment: @StefanStanković, many (and all most common) `O(n log n)` sorts not only fit into one cpp file, they usually fit into one 20-30 lines long function...

Comment: Soo... is there still an open question here? did my comment help you?

Comment: @Amit I still didn't get an answer to: How to do it without skewing the test results by decreasing the "randomness" of PRNG with interval slicing?

Comment: @Petr Didn't want to heapSort() it, because I'm pretty certain that the result would be the same: for the very long array, elements would form near-perfect linear function that's easily interpolated and that's just the result of `INT_MAX` and `RAND_MAX` values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a method to generate an ordered random sequence. This uses *Knuth's algorithm S* and taken from the book *Programming Pearls*.

This requires a function that returns a random double in the range [0,1). I included `my_rand()` as an example. I've also modified it to take an output iterator for the destination.

```
namespace
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 eng{ rd() };
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist; // [0,1)
    double my_rand() { return dist(eng); }
}

// Programming Pearls column 11.2
// Knuth's algorithm S (3.4.2)
// output M integers (in order) in range 1..N
template <typename OutIt>
void knuth_s(int M, int N, OutIt dest)
{
    double select = M, remaining = N;
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; ++i) {
        if (my_rand() < select / remaining) {
            *dest++ = i;
            --select;
        }
        --remaining;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> data;

    knuth_s(20, 200, back_inserter(data)); // 20 values in [1,200]
}
```

[Demo in ideone.com](http://ideone.com/u68Gd8)

Comment: This technique works reasonably when m is roughly similar in size to n. If m << n though, it will be slow since it takes O(n) time, whereas simply generating m integers and sorting it is O(m*log(m)).

Answer (score 2):

So you want to generate an "array" that has N unique random numbers and they must be in a sorted order?  This sounds like a perfect use for a [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set).  When inserting elements into a `set` they are sorted for us automatically and a set can only contain unique elements so it takes care of checking if the random number has already been generated.

```
std::set random_numbers;
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 mt(rd());
while (random_numbers.size() < number_of_random_numbers_needed)
{
    random_numbers.insert(mt());
}
```

Then you can convert the set to something else like a `std::vector` or `std::array` if you don't want to keep it as a set.

Comment: Sure, but I should have said the point of this program is to make everything from scratch (i.e. basic types) and asses algorithm's quality.

Comment: @StefanStanković why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Because 60-year-old Algorithms and Data Structures professor says so. I'm lucky I didn't have to make my own PRGN. :D

Comment: @StefanStanković then just implement you own `set`.  There is a lot of information online on how to make one.

Answer (score 1):

What about generating a sorted array from statistical properties ?

This probably needs some digging but you should be able to generate the integers in order by adding a random difference whose mean is the standard deviation of your overall sample.

That raises some problem at range boundaries, but given the size of your sample you can probably ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this I've decided to transfer the responsibility to built-in PRNG and do the follwing:

*Add **n*** `rand()` *results to binary **tree** and fill the array by traversing it in order (from leftmost leaf).*

Comment: What will happen if your rand() gives you the same number more than once? You will end up with less than n numbers, right?

Comment: @Boris Nope, number of elements is incremented only on successful addition, end-condition is that *n* elements are added, not generated.